# how to check checkboxes on change of option element using value and rel attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, selectlistitem

I have a page that contains a drop-down list. The options elements contain an id for the value. On change I am posting and doing a sql qry to fetch all item ids that match the option value. Then I want to add the attribute of checked to the matching checkboxs. If that makes sense.

My select list: the value attribute is the collection_id

```
<select required="" name="groupSelectList" id="groupSelectList">
    <option value="#">Group…</option>
    <option value="1">guest: The default group. Users that have not registered</option>
    <option value="2">customer: The default group for users that are customers and have an account</option>
    <option value="3">support: The default group for users of type Support</option>
    <option value="4">site_admin: The site administrator</option>
    <option value="5">support_admin: For the Support department Manager, VP etc.</option>
    <option value="26">testing group 2: This is another disposable group made just for testing</option>
    <option value="25">testing group 1: This is a disposable group. Group #1</option>
    <option value="24">test43: test43 description</option>
    <option value="23">test from new page: testing group to be deleted</option>
</select>
```

My checkboxes: the rel/value attributes are the permission_id 's

```
<ul class="four_up tiles">
    <li class="tile field">
        <label for="delete" class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" rel="1" value="1" id="delete" class="cb" name="checkbox">
            <span></span> delete</label>
    </li>
    <li class="tile field">
        <label for="administrate" class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" rel="2" value="2" id="administrate" class="cb" name="checkbox">
            <span></span> administrate
        </label>
    </li>
    <li class="tile field">
        <label for="view" class="checkbox checked">
            <input type="checkbox" rel="3" value="3" id="view" class="cb" name="checkbox">
            <span><i class="icon-check"></i></span> view
        </label>
    </li>
    <li class="tile field">
        <label for="edit" class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" rel="4" value="4" id="edit" class="cb" name="checkbox">
            <span></span> edit
        </label>
    </li>
    <li class="tile field">
        <label for="create" class="checkbox checked">
            <input type="checkbox" rel="5" value="5" id="create" class="cb" name="checkbox">
            <span><i class="icon-check"></i></span> create
        </label>
    </li>
    <li class="tile field">
        <label for="Test23" class="checkbox checked">
            <input type="checkbox" rel="6" value="6" id="Test23" class="cb" name="checkbox">
            <span><i class="icon-check"></i></span> Test23
        </label>
    </li>
    <li class="tile field">
        <label for="testing24" class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" rel="7" value="7" id="testing24" class="cb" name="checkbox">
            <span></span> testing24
        </label>
    </li>
    <li class="tile field">
        <label for="todays editor" class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" rel="8" value="8" id="todays editor" class="cb" name="checkbox">
            <span></span> todays editor
        </label>
    </li>
    <li class="tile field">
        <label for="perm name here" class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" rel="9" value="9" id="perm name here" class="cb" name="checkbox">
            <span></span> perm name here
        </label>
    </li>
    <li class="tile field">
        <label for="yada ydada ydada" class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" rel="10" value="10" id="yada ydada ydada" class="cb" name="checkbox">
            <span></span> yada ydada ydada
        </label>
    </li>
    <li class="tile field">
        <label for="test46" class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" rel="11" value="11" id="test46" class="cb" name="checkbox">
            <span></span> test46</label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and the jquery:

```
// set checks on permissions fieldset
    $("#groupSelectList").on('change', function() {
        var slct = $(this).val();
        //alert(slct);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'ajax-processing.php',
            data: {gid: slct, d: 'yes'},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                var mssg = data.msg;
                var list = mssg.replace(/^-|-$/g,'');
                var itemArr = list.split('-');
                for(var i = 1; i < itemArr.length; i++) {
                    //alert("input[rel='"+[i]+"']");
                    $("input[name='checkbox']").each(function() {
                        if($(this).attr("rel") === [i]) {
                            $("input[rel='"+[i]+"']").attr("checked","checked");
                        }
                    });
                }
                //$("<p class='alert info'>"+data.msg+" cleaned = "+list+"</p>").prependTo("#setPermsToSelectedGroup_");    
            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $("<p class='alert danger'><i class='entypo icn-thumbs-down'></i>"+errorThrown+"</p>").prependTo("#setPermsToSelectedGroup_");
            }
        });
    });
```

My MySQL query returns a "-" separated list of permission_ids based on a look-up table that contains 2 id's the collection_id and the permission_id. The permission ids list is then split by Javascript split() and I then try to iterate through all of the check-boxes to find a match from the check-box attribute of rel or value, either would work - at this point I want to set the attribute checked=checked to the corresponding check-box. I think my jQuery to is wrong. I know that the select on change is working, my MySql runs and the values returned are exactly what I am expecting. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

and the response:

```
{"error":false,"msg":"5-4-3-2-1-"}
```

Using the selector suggested in the comments and some rethinking on my part here is the solution that I ended up with. Explanation to follow:

```
for(var i = 0; i < itemArr.length; i++) {
    $("input[name='checkbox']").each(function() {
        if($(this).attr("rel") === itemArr[i]) {
            var targ = $(".cb[rel='"+itemArr[i]+"']").next();
            $("<i class='entypo icon-check'></i>").appendTo(targ);
            $(".cb[rel='"+itemArr[i]+"']").parent("label").addClass("checked");
        }
    });
}
```

Now a confession. The attribute did not need to be added I needed to append the sibling span with a checked Icon because I am using the Gumby css framework and that is the way the styled check boxes are handled. So with the correct selector I was able to solve this issue Thanks guys

Comment: post small example of data returned

Answer (score 1):

Problem is in the selector creation. You are using the index of the `for` loop, not the array element that matches that index. Also redundant to loop over every checkbox on each pass of the loop of new array

This should work

```
for(var i = 1; i < itemArr.length; i++) {             
       $(".cb[rel="+ itemArr[i] +"]").prop('checked', true);       
 }
```

Comment: using your example, that should replace the .each function as well?

Comment: yes, will be targeting specific selector right away

Comment: Your solution set me in the right direction so I +1 for that. However it was due to my own stupidity, it was late when I was writing this. The other reason, other than the selector, was my css framework I am using. In order to check the check box I needed to append an icon the the sibling span. See my solution in my edit.

Comment: Also with the .each() function I was not able to target each one for some reason. But thank you for your help :)